# Using functionality from scripts

Tags: bash

I have a bash script `linge.sh` which I call from my `.bashrc` using

`source ${HOME}/Opstk/bin/linge/linge.sh`

Now I want to include additional functionality from `linge.sh` optionally enable by calling the bash file in

`${HOME}/Opstk/bin/linge/edvart/edvart.sh`

Simply using

`source ${HOME}/Opstk/bin/linge/edvart/edvart.sh`

in

`${HOME}/Opstk/bin/linge/linge.sh` ?

I want the function calls to be available whenever a user launches the terminal.

The definitions of the functions are as follows

```
linge-environ-texinfo
{
 ...
}
export -f linge-environ-texinfo
```

When I am in the terminal, I simply want to call the function as I wish

```
linge-environ-texinfo -opt1 --opt2=val param1 param2
```

Comment: You are not calling it (executing in a subshell), you are sourcing it (executing in current shell). It is unclear what you want to achieve, please edit your question and reword.

Answer (score 0):

When you `source` a file, you're executing the commands from that file in your current shell. It's essentially no different than if you had typed in the file's contents directly into the terminal yourself, line by line. The same goes for your `.bashrc` - when it's sourced, it's just running all of those commands in your current shell, and, when it sources other files, they, too, are run in your current shell. Sourcing files can be a neat way of breaking off pieces of your `.bashrc` into different modules so you're not looking at a giant file every time you want to tweak something.

`export`, on the other hand, provides the given name/variable to commands executed from the shell it was exported from. For example, if you were to define a variable `FOO=bar` in your shell without exporting it and then ran a script expecting `FOO` to still equal "bar" in that script's context, you'd be mistaken - that extra bit of context hasn't been provided to the subshell that your script runs in, so `FOO` will be unset there. Using `export` would fix that problem because it tells the shell to provide that name and set it to a given value (if provided) for any processes spawned from it, including your script.

So, to your original question - if you're defining functions that you want to have at your disposal as soon as you run a new shell, sourcing a file containing them in your `.bashrc` will do the trick. Similarly, if you're trying to effectively import some set of functions into other files where you want to use those functions, you can just source the file(s) containing the functions into the files where you want to use them. The only time that `export` is necessary is if you're running some child process that expects access to the names you've defined.

That all having been said, in the future, remember to check `help` or `man` first when you hit problems like this - it saves you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: I wanted to call functionalities using function names as soon as I am in a terminal, that's why I added `export`.